# Is it possible to search through a huge "database" array without serious memory leaks? Maybe splitting it into pieces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, memory-leaks

I have a really huge array, it may contain millions of objects and looks like

```
    srcArray = [{
        'name': 'AAA',
        'keyA': true,
        'keyB': 'blahblah'
    }, 
    //...
    {
        'name': 'ZZZ',
        'keyA': false,
        'keyB': 'testString'
    }];
```

I will have to find every matching object and put it into another array. The problem is we cannot put this single array into memory because it's too big to deal with. The idea is to split it into small parts, get the first part, do something, then replace it by the next piece ... and so on, till the last piece. See this example (for three very small pieces):

Part 1, file **part1.js**:

```
    srcArray = [{
        'name': 'A1',
        'boolA': false,
        'strB': 'testString'
    }, {
        'name': 'B1',
        'boolA': false,
        'strB': 'blahblah'
    }, {
        'name': 'C1',
        'boolA': true,
        'strB': 'blahblah'
    }];
```

Part 2, file **part2.js**:

```
    srcArray = [{
        'name': 'A2',
        'boolA': false,
        'strB': 'blahblah'
    }, {
        'name': 'B2',
        'boolA': true,
        'strB': 'testString'
    }, {
        'name': 'C2',
        'boolA': false,
        'strB': 'blahblah'
    }];
```

Part 3, file **part3.js**:

```
    srcArray = [{
        'name': 'A3',
        'boolA': true,
        'strB': 'blahblah'
    }, {
        'name': 'B3',
        'boolA': false,
        'strB': 'blahblah'
    }, {
        'name': 'C3',
        'boolA': false,
        'strB': 'testString'
    }];
```

The code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            srcArray = [];
            found = [];
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var loadScripts = function (scripts) {
                        var result = function () {
                                delete srcArray; 
                                srcArray = undefined;
                                console.log(found);
                            }
                        var func = function (i) {
                                if (i >= scripts.length) return result();
                                var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                                var scr = document.createElement('script');
                                scr.src = scripts[i];
                                var f = false;
                                scr.onload = scr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                                    if (!f && (!scr.readyState || scr.readyState == "loaded" || scr.readyState == "complete")) {
                                        f = true;
                                        search('testString', srcArray);
                                        setTimeout(function () {
                                            func(++i)
                                        }, 50);
                                        scr.onload = scr.onreadystatechange = null;
                                        if (head && scr.parentNode) {
                                            head.removeChild(scr);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                return head.insertBefore(scr, head.firstChild);
                            }
                        func(0);
                    }
                function search(s, arr) {
                    for (var i = arr.length; i--;) {
                        for (key in arr[i]) {
                            if (typeof (arr[i][key]) === 'string' && arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key) && arr[i][key].indexOf(s) > -1) found.push(arr[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    return found;
                };
                $('.click').click(function () {
                    delete found; 
                    found = undefined;
                    srcArray = [];
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        found = [];
                        loadScripts(["part1.js", "part2.js", "part3.js"])
                    }, 50);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="click">click me</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Yes, I realize that global variables are ugly, but I can't see another way. I tested this code with 10 parts (each array contained 250k objects, that is, 10 parts contained 2.5 million objects, total data size is about 260MB). It took about 20 seconds to complete this test, but I don't care about the time, I do care about memory: Firefox was the best occupying 140MB RAM after 4 clicks (it means that the browser searched within more than 1 GB of script data! a very good result!), Chrome and Opera 11.52 were much worse, and IE9 just failed at the second click with about 1GB of RAM after the first click.

Question 1. Is it possible to solve this kind of problem by Javascript? Is it possible to search through a huge data and avoid memory leak?

Question 2. How to stop the process? That is, when I click some `#stop` element, the function must stop and release that `found` array (it will contain as much objects as the function have already found).

Comment: setInterval is faster than using `setTimeout`.  Also, if you want to stop it, you will have to clear the Timeout or the Interval.  Again, suggest using setInterval, than you won't have to worry about using the setTimeout function again within the `loadScripts` function.  If you set it to a variable, than you can use clearInterval(variableName); to clear it and stop it, and just output the results of `found[]`

Comment: May I ask what this is being used for? Is it possible to process the array with PHP and AJAX?

Comment: Ok, so looks like he is loading up javascript files that have an array defined in it, which I would assume he is using the array elsewhere within the page.  If he loads it using PHP, he'd have to cut the array off somehow and than assign it to a js variable, which would probably be faster, if he can cut the file somehow.  For example, putting a bunch of text somewhere in the js file to indicate to stop reading the file line by line with php.

Comment: @SolomonClosson: On 1st comment, `setTimeout` is often used in complicated situations to add asynchronous behavior and get rid of a "true recursion". I don't think there's a big problem with that.

Comment: @Ray: No, a completely client-side code is required. Process this array with AJAX only - how?

Comment: Wow, you're really pushing the limits of the browser - 1GB memory allocation to a single page!!